# NestJS POST Request: Body is always empty

Tags: api, rest, post, nestjs, body-parser

I am quite new to NestJS and I make a small Client Server Programm with NestJS and AurelliaJS. The problem is, when I send a JSON Object in Body. It is always empty when I access it with @Body() body:DTOBody at the Server.

Here are some code Snippets:

Client:
Here i build my request and call my API Service.
`

```
public async genereateGraph(cd_algorithm: string, recovery_algorithm: string, delimiter?: string, identifier?: string){
        const headers = {session: await SessionService.ensureSession()};
        delimiter = ",";
        const requestBody: IStartCausalDiscovery = {delimiter, cd_algorithm, recovery_algorithm};
                
        const result = await ApiService.post<SuccessResponse>(
        '/CausalDiscovery/generate',
        JSON.stringify(requestBody),
        undefined,
         {
           session: await SessionService.ensureSession()
         },
        );

        return result.success;
    }
```

Here I make the actual request. The Body Parameter looks like: body: "{"delimiter":",","cd_algorithm":"ANM","recovery_algorithm":"ARD"}"

```
  public static async post<T>(route: string, body?: BodyInit, query?: queryString.StringifiableRecord, headers?: Record<string, string>): Promise<T> {
    let url = `${BASE_URL}${route}`;
    if(query != null) {
      url += `?${queryString.stringify(query)}`;
    }

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: body,
        headers: headers
      })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
          if(data.success != true) {
            throw new Error(data.errorMessage);
          }
          resolve(data);
        })
        .catch(err => reject(err));
    });
  }
```

`

Server:

The Service at the Server is executed. I also get a correct result in Session. Bud my Body is empty: {}.
`

```
@Controller('/CausalDiscovery')
export class CausalDiscoveryController{
    constructor(private readonly causalDiscoverySercive: CausalDiscoveryService){}

    @Post('/generate')
    public async generateGraph(
        @Body() body:IStartCausalDiscovery,
        @Session() session: string,
        ):Promise<SuccessResponse>{
            console.log(body);
            console.log(session);
            this.causalDiscoverySercive.generateGraph(session, body.cd_algorithm, body.recovery_algorithm);
            return {success: true};
        }
```

`
I hope someone can help me. I am quite new to NestJs and AurelliaJs. Did I forget something basically?

Best regards.

I already tried to sent the body with FormData and to get it with @Req() at server side.

Comment: Do you need to set the `Content-Type` header?

Comment: @lorenz In the controller, when you call the `generateGraph` function, you're passing the `session` as the first argument. But, in the service file, the same function is expecting one of the request fields in the first parameter but not the session. Is that causing the issue? But it shouldn't be empty though